# Excel Transformation from rows to columns

Tags: excel, pivot, ssis-2012

I have an excel sheet getting generated from a SSIS package. It gets stored in the below format.
[image]

I want this data to be transformed into the following format,
[image]

All my column values are in text format(Stored procedure returns them as NVARCHAR). I could not use SQL pivot because the values are dynamic. Based on the start and the end date, the number of rows in screen shot 1 can be more. Excel pivot did not work because the data is not in numerical format. How should I proceed with this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You can do this in Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.  But I don't see where **CHP** in the first column is coming from.

Comment: Sorry instead of CHP it should be XYZ. The organization doesn't have Excel 2010 and above. Nevertheless, can you give any links that may help for this kind of task, so that i may try

Comment: What version of Excel do they have?   There are numerous examples on this forum of converting columnar data to rows (and vice versa) using power query. I don't have time to do that work for you this morning.  However, PQ would require a "refresh" when your data changes.  You could do this manually, or with an Excel VBA event procedure.

Comment: they have Excel 2003 version. I tried using some of the answers here, but none of them are giving the results. Also, i can't refresh every time, maybe make a template and fill it with data in SSIS.

Comment: Can you change the text values to numeric values in any way? Maybe with VALUE function or something?

Comment: If you have Excel 2003, I would suggest a VBA solution with event code to accomplish the "refresh" when the data changes.  I think  a formula would be too cumbersome and difficult to maintain, even if feasible.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes, I can change the stored procedure to return numerical values. It that case, would it be possible?

Comment: Could be. Maybe even with Pivot Tables. But we don't know how is your data stored and how do you make the calculations so not tested. You could give it a try